# Why does Helium make your voice change?

Tags: communication

When we breathe in helium and then speak, our voice changes drastically. Does it happen only due to helium or can happen if we use other gas? What factors of the gas does our voice depend on (like density, temperatue etc.)

Comment: Any gas less dense than the mix of N2 and O2 we call "air". The precise explanation is too complex for biology SE, here it is at Physics SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122353/why-does-our-voice-sound-different-on-inhaling-helium

Answer (score -1):

Helium is not as dense as air, and when your vocal cord vibrate with the helium, it vibrates at a higher frequency, making your voice higher. sulfur hexafluoride Is Denser than air, making your voice deeper.